# different analyzers in different fields

Tags: elasticsearch

Because in my mapping below, when I put the URL field with the analyzer different from the title and description fields when I do a search simultaneously in the three fields, it doesn't return anything even if I have one of the three words below in each field

```
 {
      "settings": {
        "index": {
          "number_of_shards": "5",
          "number_of_replicas": "0",
          "analysis": {
            "filter": {
              "stemmer_plural_portugues": {
                "name": "minimal_portuguese",
                "stopwords" : ["http", "https", "ftp", "www"],
                "type": "stemmer"
              },
              
              
                "synonym_filter": {
                "type": "synonym",
                "lenient": true,
                "synonyms_path": "analysis/synonym.txt",
                "updateable" : true
    
              },
              
           
              "shingle_filter": {
                "type": "shingle",
                "min_shingle_size": 2,
                "max_shingle_size": 3
              }
    
            },
            
            "analyzer": {
              "analyzer_customizado": {
                "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "stemmer_plural_portugues",
                  "asciifolding",
                  "synonym_filter",
                  "shingle_filter" ],
                "tokenizer": "standard"
              },
              
              
               "analyzer_url": {
                "filter": [
                  "lowercase",
                  "stemmer_plural_portugues",
                  "asciifolding" ],
                "tokenizer": "lowercase"
              }
              
              
            }
    
          }
        }
      },
      "mappings": {
          "properties": {
    
            "id": {
             "type": "long"
            },
             "data": {
              "type": "date"
            },
             "quebrado": {
              "type": "byte"
              
            },
             "pgrk": {
               "type":  "integer" 
            },
             "url_length": {
               "type":  "integer" 
            },
            "title": {
              "analyzer": "analyzer_customizado",
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "ignore_above": 256,
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "description": {
            "analyzer": "analyzer_customizado",
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "ignore_above": 256,
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            },
            "url": {
              "analyzer": "analyzer_url",
              "type": "text",
              "fields": {
                "keyword": {
                  "ignore_above": 256,
                  "type": "keyword"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
```

in the query below the three words exist each of the fields, but it only returns results if I search for words that are in the title and in the description, if I also search for the word that is in the URL field that has the different analyzer does not return anything.

if I search only the words that are in the title and description field you will normally find, if I search only the word that is in the URL field also finds it, however if I search for the three words that exist in the three fields it doesn't return anything.

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    
    "query": {
      
            
                "multi_match": {
                    "query": "carro moto aviao",
                     "type": "cross_fields",
                    "fields": [
                        "title",
                        "description",
                        "url"
                    ],
                    "operator": "and"
              }

    }
}
```

Comment: can you also add sample docs so that we can test this on your data?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are using the `operator` as `and` which means all three words `carro moto aviao` must present, can you change it to `OR` and see if its returns result.

**Adding a working example with you mapping, sample data and with search query with `or` parameter and confirming that it works.**

**Sample doc**

```
{
    "title": "carro",
    "description": "moto",
    "url": "aviao"
}
```

**Search query with `OR` param**

```
{
    "from": 0,
    "size": 10,
    "query": {
        "multi_match": {
            "query": "carro moto aviao",
            "type": "cross_fields",
            "fields": [
                "title",
                "description",
                "url"
            ],
            "operator": "or"
        }
    }
}
```

**Search result**

```
 "hits": [
            {
                "_index": "jean",
                "_type": "_doc",
                "_id": "1",
                "_score": 0.5753642,
                "_source": {
                    "title": "carro",
                    "description": "moto",
                    "url": "aviao"
                }
            }
        ]
```

**Note: confirmed that it doesn't work with `and` param if your query.**

Comment: I have to return documents that have all the words searched, so I use AND. Since the three searched words exist in the records, then it should be returned. However it does not return due to the URL field having the different analyzer, if the three fields are with the same analyzer it works.

Comment: @Jean can you add sample docs and expected documents so that I can further help, btw I used your index mapping and did you get a chance to try my example ?

Comment: I added the example